# iOS: layoutIfNeeded doesn't seem to work in updating view following change in constraints (Xcode 6.4, Swift 1.2)

Tags: layout, uiview, xcode6, constraints, uiviewanimation

I am working on a chat app and am trying to get my view to change when the keyboard comes in. The input textfield is at the bottom of my view, and I want it to go up when it is clicked and the keyboard appears. The textField is in a small UIView called dockView under a tableView where the message swill be displayed. The dockView's height has a constraint referenced as dockViewHeight that is equal to 47 at the beginning. So I use this method with UITextFieldDelegate:

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {
    println("did")
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: {
        println("go \(self.dockViewHeight.constant)")
        self.dockViewHeight.constant = 400
        println("go \(self.dockViewHeight.constant)")
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        println("go \(self.dockViewHeight.constant)")
        }, completion: nil)
}
```

The method is called, as everything is printed to the console. The contraints are also updated as you can see her in the logs:

```
did
go 47.0
go 400.0
go 400.0
```

However, there is no change on the screen and the dockView's height remains the same. Any idea as to why this is happening?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should set your constraint outside of the animation block, and only call `layoutIfNeeded` within the block.